# Не срабатывает функция show в jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Вот пример кода (кусочек) на php:

```
foreach ($categories as $value) {   
    echo "<div class=\"dish_category\">$value</div>";       
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {            
        if ($row['category'] == $value) {   
            echo "<div class=\"dish\">";            
                echo "<p class=\"dish_name\">".$row['name_of_dish']."</p>";
                echo "<p>".$row['discription']."</p>"; 
                echo "<p>".$row['weight']." г"."</p>";
                echo "<p>".$row['price']." гр"."</p>";
            echo "</div>";
        }           
    }       
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
}
```

А вот jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".dish").hide();
});

$(".dish_category").click(function () {   
  $(".dish").show();    
});
```

Я бы хотел что бы содержимое блока dish_category изначально было скрыто, а при клике по этому же блоку - показывалось. Скрывается оно нормально, но вот по клику не открывается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка.

Вот текст, сгенерированый php:

```
    <div class="dish_category">Блюда на компанию</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Три товарища</p><p>Люля кебаб из баранины, свиная шея, куриное филе, картофель по-деревенски</p><p>1000 г</p><p>400 гр</p></div><div class="dish_category">Блюда от шефа</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Овощи в устричном соусе</p><p>Брокколи, цветная капуста, морковь, перец болгарский, рис, устричный соус </p><p>300 г</p><p>69 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат с телятиной</p><p>Тёплый салат с телятиной, баклажанами, черри и кунжутом под оригинальным соусом</p><p>300 г</p><p>85 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Салат "Шафран"</p><p>Куриная печень, цуккини, грибы, помидор, огурец, микс салата с оригинальным соусом </p><p>250 г</p><p>75 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Ночная охота</p><p>Свинина с луком, болгарским перцем, рисом и с соусом от Шефа </p><p>300 г</p><p>125 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Курица по-Азиатски</p><p>Куриное бедро с рисом, морковью, пекинской капустой и куриным яйцом с азиатским соусом </p><p>300 г</p><p>105 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish_category">Основные блюда</div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Телятина с фрикасе из шампиньонов</p><p>Телятина на картофельной подушке с грибным соусом </p><p>200 г</p><p>138 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Куриные рулетики с сыром в сливочном соусе</p><p></p><p>200 г</p><p>80 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Утиная грудка в клюквенном соусе</p><p></p><p>170 г</p><p>128 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Мясо по-французски</p><p></p><p>200 г</p><p>90 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Чёрная курица</p><p>Нежное сочетание граната с восточными пряностями </p><p>170 г</p><p>79 гр</p></div><div class="dish_category">Салаты</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Греческий</p><p></p><p>280 г</p><p>65 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Салат из свежих овощей</p><p></p><p>240 г</p><p>59 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат в азиатском стиле</p><p>Необычное сочетание свиной вырезки и куриного филе под овощным миксом </p><p>280 г</p><p>79 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Оливье с телятиной</p><p></p><p>300 г</p><p>74 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Фреш салат с лососем, мидиями и с сыром фета</p><p></p><p>250 г</p><p>135 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат с морепродуктами</p><p></p><p>250 г</p><p>125 гр</p></div>      <form action="new_dish.php" method="post" class="new_dish">
```

Этот php код я подключаю через include в основной файл php и там же подключаю файлы js. Хочу заметить что блоки .dish скрываются нормально, так что по-идее не в путях дело.

Comment: Лучше добавьте в пример HTML который сгенерирован вашим  кодом, чем код который вырван из контекста

Comment: [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: где подключен скрипт с твоим кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать так... Возможно что его еще нет в DOM как вариант, но хорошо что б привели еще HTML... This?)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".dish").hide();

  $(".dish_category").click(function () {   
    $(".dish").show();    
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dish_category">Блюда на компанию</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Три товарища</p><p>Люля кебаб из баранины, свиная шея, куриное филе, картофель по-деревенски</p><p>1000 г</p><p>400 гр</p></div><div class="dish_category">Блюда от шефа</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Овощи в устричном соусе</p><p>Брокколи, цветная капуста, морковь, перец болгарский, рис, устричный соус </p><p>300 г</p><p>69 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат с телятиной</p><p>Тёплый салат с телятиной, баклажанами, черри и кунжутом под оригинальным соусом</p><p>300 г</p><p>85 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Салат "Шафран"</p><p>Куриная печень, цуккини, грибы, помидор, огурец, микс салата с оригинальным соусом </p><p>250 г</p><p>75 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Ночная охота</p><p>Свинина с луком, болгарским перцем, рисом и с соусом от Шефа </p><p>300 г</p><p>125 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Курица по-Азиатски</p><p>Куриное бедро с рисом, морковью, пекинской капустой и куриным яйцом с азиатским соусом </p><p>300 г</p><p>105 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish_category">Основные блюда</div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Телятина с фрикасе из шампиньонов</p><p>Телятина на картофельной подушке с грибным соусом </p><p>200 г</p><p>138 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Куриные рулетики с сыром в сливочном соусе</p><p></p><p>200 г</p><p>80 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Утиная грудка в клюквенном соусе</p><p></p><p>170 г</p><p>128 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Мясо по-французски</p><p></p><p>200 г</p><p>90 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Чёрная курица</p><p>Нежное сочетание граната с восточными пряностями </p><p>170 г</p><p>79 гр</p></div><div class="dish_category">Салаты</div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Греческий</p><p></p><p>280 г</p><p>65 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Салат из свежих овощей</p><p></p><p>240 г</p><p>59 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат в азиатском стиле</p><p>Необычное сочетание свиной вырезки и куриного филе под овощным миксом </p><p>280 г</p><p>79 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Оливье с телятиной</p><p></p><p>300 г</p><p>74 гр</p></div><div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Фреш салат с лососем, мидиями и с сыром фета</p><p></p><p>250 г</p><p>135 гр</p></div>
    <div class="dish"><p class="dish_name">Тёплый салат с морепродуктами</p><p></p><p>250 г</p><p>125 гр</p></div>      <form action="new_dish.php" method="post" class="new_dish">
```

Comment: а что должен делать приведенный код?

Comment: я просто перенес обработчик в функцию ready...

Comment: стоит дописать пояснение в ответ

Comment: Так работает.. Спасибо! Только не совсем понятно, почему именно нужно после загрузки документа, потому что если я подожду секунд 5-10 после загрузки, то функция все равно не работает, но документ ведь явно уже загружен...Получается все функции нужно писать именно после ready?

Comment: не забудьте поставить птичку рядом) не знаю точного механизма работ вашего документа, но луче делать так...

Comment: Да желательно писать все в ready!